# How to setup two Linux VPS servers to act as a traffic/data relay

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, openvpn, relay

I have two VPS servers running Ubuntu located in different regions. How can I utilize these two servers to act as a data relay, shown in this diagram:

Client --> VPS1 ----> VPS2 ----> Internet

So far VPS1 has is running OpenVPN server but I would like to forward all the traffic to VPS2. If anyone has any idea how I could achieve this that would be great.

Thanks.